# C# Process.Start() with multiple arguments do not work (nmap)

Tags: c#, nmap, process.start

**Description**

At the moment I am trying to call "nmap" through C# Process.Start(). But I can't get it work with my desired input arguments.
At Process.Start() it seems to make a false parsing of the arguments.
Do you know how I have to write the ArgumentList that my command is running right?
In the commandline the same command works like charm...

Thank you!

**Example**

My simple example: (Edit: Suggestion of Lei Yang)

```
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var myprocess = Process.Start
            (
                new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/zsh",
                    ArgumentList = {"-c nmap -p 8000-9000 -oG - 192.168.178.37/24 | awk -F'[/ ]' '{h=$2; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==\"open\"){print h,$(i-1)}}}'" }

                }
            );

            myprocess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output of this command:**

```
zsh: bad option string: '-c nmap -p 8000-9000 -oG - 192.168.178.37/24 | awk -F'[/ ]' '{h=$2; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="open"){print h,$(i-1)}}}''
```

**Desired output:**

```
192.168.178.1 8089
192.168.178.1 8181
192.168.178.1 8182
192.168.178.1 8183
192.168.178.1 8184
192.168.178.1 8185
192.168.178.1 8186
192.168.178.43 8080
```

Comment: nmap doesn't know what "|" means, pipes require support from the command processor.  You'll have to execute cmd.exe /c nmap etcetera

Comment: The script is running on linux.
If I write the same command in the command line nmap has no problem with the pipe....
There is only a problem at parsing with the C# Process() class...
Could the problem be the spaces between the arguments?

Comment: try use `bash -c 'nmap ...'`, in C# `FileName = "/bin/bash"`

Comment: You mean?
`                        FileName = "/bin/bash",
                        ArgumentList = {"-c 'nmap'"}`

Then I have this output
/bin/bash: - : ivalid option

Comment: try ArgumentList = {"’-c nmap ... '"}` [ref](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144514/add-arguments-to-bash-c) make sure single quotes are around the parameters?

Comment: Please change your question to show the code you are currently trying. `nmap` does not understand pipes, you mush use `/bin/bash` as the process and then pass the proper arguments to it.

Comment: @NetMage: I changed my question to the suggestion of Lei Yang. I try to only call "nmap" without any parameters...just for testing.

Comment: `ArgumentList` is a collection of `string`s, not a single `string`. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.argumentlist?view=net-6.0). You need to pass in `ArgumentList = { "-c",  "'nmap'" }`

Comment: Have you tried to use or to have a look about this nmap wrapper in c# ?https://github.com/thomdixon/SaltwaterTaffy

Comment: The code in the example is difficult to follow and should probably be cleaned up. It's not clear why you have 2 commented out lines with `ArgumentList`.

The try/catch can be removed; it's not doing anything as it just rethrows any exception.

Comment: @ReillyWood Sorry I did not mean to make you angry. Now I deleted the not nessessary lines I hope i fullfill your requirements.

Comment: @Gambi thank you for the link I have already seen the wrapper. Maybe I would try it, but the last change is about 5 years ago... Maybe the wrapper is deprecated...

Comment: @NetMage Thank you your suggestion works! I will update in a short moment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of you I could solve the problem.
Thank you!

Solution for someone with the same problem:

Variant 1:
Direct way:

```
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var myprocess = Process.Start
            (
                new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/zsh",
                    ArgumentList = {  "-c",  "nmap -p 8000-9000 -oG - 192.168.178.37/24 | awk -F'[/ ]' '{h=$2; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i==\"open\"){print h,$(i-1)}}}'" }

                }
            );

            myprocess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Variant 2:
Detour: Shell script
(Maybe the easier way)
C#:

```
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace MyApp // Note: actual namespace depends on the project name.
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var myprocess = Process.Start
            (
                new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "/bin/zsh",
                    ArgumentList = {"/home/alexander/tst.sh"}
                }
            );

            myprocess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
nmap -p 8000-9000 -oG - 192.168.178.37/24 | awk -F'[/ ]' '{h=$2; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="open"){print h,$(i-1)}}}'
```

Output of both variants:

```
192.168.178.1 8089
192.168.178.1 8181
192.168.178.1 8182
192.168.178.1 8183
192.168.178.1 8184
192.168.178.1 8185
192.168.178.1 8186
192.168.178.43 8080
```